# OS X or X11 terminal emulator supporting proportional fonts

Tags: macos, terminal, fonts

Does anybody know of a terminal emulator for Mac OS X supporting proportional fonts?

Preferably a native app, otherwise for X11. Preferably with correct line-wrapping at the window edge, not at a certain number of characters.

I've gotten used to programming in a proportional font (Verdana 13pt) and I'd like to get the same look in my terminal windows.

I'm well aware that full-screen (curses) programs would not render correctly on a proportional font, but I seldom use any. Most of my terminal work involves Bash, compilers, and other line-oriented tools, which should work perfectly well with a proportional font.

For the sake of argument here is some code in my current editor configuration, which I find very readable:

[image]

I assume such a terminal emulator should advertise having very long lines, in order to do all the line-wrapping at the display level, instead of making Readline and other "smart" interactive CLI do it themselves. Other than that, I do not see why it should not be possible.

In fact, I might as well go ahead and do it myself, if I cannot find any.

Again, I'm aware Curses and other character-counting applications (such as the output of `ls -l`) would display incorrectly. Dealing correctly with those, with some form of heuristic or "elastic tabstops" would be a plus, but not a strict requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs is available for Mac OS X, supports proportional fonts, and has a terminal emulator. There are a number of Emacs versions available for OS X, so hopefully you can find one you like that has both the fonts and terminal emulator. A possible candidate is Aquamacs, http://aquamacs.org/features.shtml.

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought of that. I'll wait to see if there is any other option a bit more user friendly (without the M-x C-r M-a M-x nonsense) otherwise I'll accept yours.

Comment: You could put the startup commands in your `~/.emacs` [init file](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InitFile), or if you want to use Emacs as an editor as well, in a separate init file that you load only when starting Emacs as a terminal (`-l ~/terminal-init.el`).

Comment: @Tobia Did you mean to accept this answer but not award the bounty for it?  If not (since it seems like stevek_mcc's answer helped you), you only have a few hours left to award it!

Comment: @stevek_mcc I'm upvoting your answer (from 1 to 2) so that you still get some bounty even if Tobia does not assign it to you.  (You'll at least get half of it for hitting the +2 vote threshold.  :)

Comment: What are you talking about? An accepted answer gets the bounty automatically at the end of the period, unless a better answer comes along first.

Comment: For a followup question about how to get Emacs to display the requested 
behavior, see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80572/how-can-i-use-emacs-under-linux-mint-as-a-proportional-font-evil-mode-editor-and.